# Regex to allow only select characters of alphabet

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex

Can someone define a regex set that would only allow two letters "E" and "P".

I have a web app where certain text areas need to allow entry of just those two characters.

Thank you.

Comment: This is easy to do, what have you tried so far ? What is blocking you ? See the "related" list on the right ...

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[ep]+$/
```

That's it.

- `^` means "Start of string"
- `[ep]` is our characters "e" and "p"
- `+` means "repeated 1 or more times"
- `$` means "end of string"

In case you also want to accept E and P as well, you can add an `i` modifier for case-insensitivity:

```
/^[ep]+$/i
```

To use in javascript:

```
var testingRegex = /^[ep]+$/i;

if (testingRegex.match(myString)) {
    //Yes, it matches!
} else {
    //Error!
}
```

Comment: You may also add `i` flag in case he needs case independence.